# Phonegap - FB.getLoginStatus always returns true

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm building an app with phonegap 3.0.0, Android 4.2 and the phonegap-facebook plugin https://github.com/jimzim/phonegap-facebook-android-sample

I'm checking if the user is logged in through Facebook. But no matter what, I always get a response of "conncted".

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
              alert('in the if');
              alert('uid is ');
              alert(response.authResponse.userID);
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
              alert('in the else if');
          } else {
              alert('in the else');
          }
         }, true);
```

The "true" parameter ensures that a request is sent to facebook servers and it's not just the cached response which is returned. However, even when I delete the app from my Facebook settings, log out of facebook from the native app and log out from the browser, I always get a value of "connected".

Also, the userID comes back as "undefined" but the accessToken is returned correctly. Any ideas?